# Removing pause between loop iterations in a Flash movie

Tags: adobe-flash

I work with a creative services that has created a Flash animation for a page my team is building out. The animation was created using Flash Catalyst, and we're experiencing an issue where, once the animation gets to the end of its loop, it pauses for around half of a second before it starts over again. We're looking for the transition to be smooth.

We have `auto-play` and `loop` checked in the options. Is there something else about the method of exporting the movie in Flash Catalyst that could be causing this undesired pause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no delay if the start and end keyframes are identical and there is no pause within the animation itself. The only thing that occurs to me is that if it's a huge file there may be a buffering lag, in which case the answer is to reduce the size of the file by allowing greater compression of the images.

There are swf decompilers like [Sothink](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) that will let you bring the swf into Flash for tuning and modification.

I would do something like this in Flash directly, where I have full control of the ActionScript, size and compression. In fact, these days, if this were for the web and/or tablet I would export from Flash as HTML/js rather than swf, or I would build it from scratch in Adobe Edge.

Comment: We tried taking the same video and exporting it in Flash Professional (rather than Flash Catalyst) and it worked as expected. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

same issue as you posted, I recommend you also make sure auto-play and loop are checked...if this does not solve your issue... delete all key frames after your last frame. It sounds silly but after your last key frame select or highlight all of the "empty or erased" keyframes that may have moved over (EVEN IF THEY ARE EMPTY) and say "remove frames". Even if they are clear, they are still place holders in flash. This is what worked for me!